# Xpath, strip @src extraction?

Tags: xpath

In Xpath 1.0, guess this is impossible, but I give it a shot..

XML

```
<img src="/media/brand_microsoft.png">
```

Xpath:

```
//div[@id='logo']/img/@src
```

Output becomes:

```
/media/brand_microsoft.png
```

Is it anyway of excluding **/media/brand_** and **.png**? So I just get:

```
microsoft
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
substring-before(substring-after(/img/@src, '/media/brand_'), '.png')
```

> **substring-before** :
>
> Returns the start of string1 before string2 occurs in it
>
> Example: substring-before('12/10','/')
>   Result: '12'
>
> **substring-after** :
>   Returns the remainder of string1 after string2 occurs in it
>
> Example: substring-after('12/10','/')
>   Result: '10'

[[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)]

**UPDATE :**

tested in http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html with :

xml input :

```
<img src="/media/brand_Barcardi_Breezer.png"/>
```

xpath expression :

```
substring-before(substring-after(/img/@src, '/media/brand_'), '.png')
```

ouput :

```
'Barcardi_Breezer'
```

Comment: I am using Xpath Helper and /html/body//div[@id='logosmall']/img[substring-before(substring-after(@src, '/media/brand_'), '.png')] highlights the correct element but dosen´t extract anything.

Comment: try this way instead :  `substring-before(substring-after(/html/body//div[@id='logosmall']/img/@src, '/media/brand_'), '.png')`

Comment: This is working very good. Only problem if the picture is named something like `<img src="/media/brand_Barcardi_Breezer.png">` the output becomes `barcardibreezer` - is it possible to make it `barcardi breezer` instead?

Comment: see my update, I tested with that xml input and the output is "bacardi_breezer" as expected